# Is there an equivalent to emacs' rx macro in python?

Tags: python, regex, emacs

The rx macro in emacs (see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/rx and http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/rx) makes it possible to specify regular expressions in a modular and readable way (at least you don't have to take care about quoting issues).  For example:

```
(rx "a" (optional "c") "b")
```

results in

```
"ac?b"
```

Is there something comparable in python?

Comment: I think it's hard to make something similar because of low flexibility of Python's syntax. DSLs are not popular in Python, usually only Java-style "builders". Closest alternative will be `re.X` and `"""` multiline strings.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, using LISP syntax to define RegEx is not a classic usage. How can one maintain that? The RegEx language is nearly a standard; readable by nearly everyone; `rx` is not. Do you know `Omnimark`? It has a pretty but verbose syntax. It is forgotten now…

To do that you can define simple function, eg.:

```
def optional(regex):
    return regex + "?"


def regex(*args):
    return "".join(args)


REGEX = regex("a", optional("b"), "c")
print(REGEX)
```

You'll get:

```
ab?c
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I did not mean to convey that I wanted to use lisp syntax in Python.  And, yes, your example demonstrates how such a package could be implemented.  I am not, however, planning to implement such a thing myself, but was rather interested to know if it already exists.  And, in emacs, to my knowing, the use of rx is not uncommon.  In particular as it allows to re-use regexp expressions for the construction of larger regexps, which you otherwise have to implement manually using concat operations, and which can really get ugly.